# Can't Load Google Chart Using Json File with JSP

Tags: json, ajax, jsp, charts, google-visualization

Im using Google charts API to load a pie chart from json file data
Here is where the chart is created (The HTML File) :

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    
    // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      
    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      
    function drawChart() {
       
     var jsonData =   $.ajax({
                    url: "read.jsp",               
                    dataType: "json"                   
                  });
          
          
      // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
      var data = new  google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

      // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
      var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, {width: 400, height: 240});
    } 
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
    <div id="chart_div" ></div>aa
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is the Read.jsp Used in url (ajax) :

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" import="java.io.*, java.net.*"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>JSP Reading Text File</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
String fileName = "/WEB-INF/json/test.json";
InputStream ins = application.getResourceAsStream(fileName);
try
{
    if(ins == null)
    {
        response.setStatus(response.SC_NOT_FOUND);
    }
    else
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader((new InputStreamReader(ins)));
        String data;
        while((data= br.readLine())!= null)
        {
            out.println(data+"<br>");
        }
    }   
}
catch(IOException e)
{
out.println(e.getMessage());
}
%>
</body>
</html>
```

And as a result I get this Error "**Table has no columns**" : 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFNHP.png)

Anyone Know why please ? and thank you

Comment: Yes it is in that format : 
{
  "cols": [
        {"id":"","label":"Topping","pattern":"","type":"string"},
        {"id":"","label":"Slices","pattern":"","type":"number"}
      ],
  "rows": [
        {"c":[{"v":"Mushrooms","f":null},{"v":3,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Onions","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Olives","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Zucchini","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Pepperoni","f":null},{"v":2,"f":null}]}
      ]
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by default, `$.ajax` is asynchronous,
need to wait on the `done` callback...

see following snippet...

```
function drawChart() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "read.jsp",
    dataType: "json"
  }).done(function (jsonData) {
    // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
    var data = new  google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

    // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, {width: 400, height: 240});
  });
}
```

**EDIT**

also, remove all the html from the jsp file,
this should be all you need...

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="application/json; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8" import="java.io.*, java.net.*"%>
<%
String fileName = "/WEB-INF/json/test.json";
InputStream ins = application.getResourceAsStream(fileName);
try
{
    if(ins == null)
    {
        response.setStatus(response.SC_NOT_FOUND);
    }
    else
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader((new InputStreamReader(ins)));
        String data;
        while((data= br.readLine())!= null)
        {
            out.println(data);
        }
    }
}
catch(IOException e)
{
out.println(e.getMessage());
}
%>
```

Comment: i thought because of the read.jsp is not returning a JSON  string

Comment: `\n\n<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd\">\n<html>\n<head>\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\">\n<title>JSP Reading Text File</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n    \n{<br>\r\n  \"cols\": [<br>\r\n        {\"id\":\"\",\"label\":\"Topping\",\"pattern\":\"\",\"type\":\"string\"},<br>\r\n        {\"id\":\"\",\"label\":\"Slices\",\"pattern\":\"\",\"type\":\"number\"}<br>\r\n      ],<br>\r\n  \"rows\": [<br>\r\n        {\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Mushrooms\",\"f\":null},{\"v\":3,\"f\":null}]},<br>\r\n    `

Comment: this is the new jsonData content

Comment: it seams that read.jsp is returning the hole html format response